# How to get followers/following listing from mysql query

Tags: mysql

This is my followers /following database table schema.
I want to fetch all data for a particular user. eg user_id **6** is following **7,8,9** and is followed by **7**. My purpose is to find if that particular user follows his followers. How can I achieve that?

```
id     |   user_id   |  follower_id
------------------------------------
1            6             7
2            6             8
3            7             6
4            8             15
5            6             9
6            5             7
```

Comment: Okay, What have you done so far?  Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I think you have to use a query with a GROUP BY statement

Comment: What does this mean `i want to list all this listing that if user_id 6 gets his followers then also get that he is also follow to that user or not.`

Answer (score 5):

You can `use separate queries`:

To get **followers**:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.follower_id) as followers FROM test_f t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 6
```

To get **following**:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.user_id) as following FROM test_f t2 WHERE t2.follower_id = 6
```

Comment: that you have to check.. i just post that query could be like this

Comment: @SomnathMuluk i made separate query as you can try

Comment: I have tried to get in same query for both results.

Comment: hey great.. @SomnathMuluk it will also helpfull

Answer (score 4):

I have added [dummy table data here](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/sql.php?db=test123&table=followers&token=9e380a32e6d67c6f4f11ea34df635c8e):

You will get follower list of each user as:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT follower_id SEPARATOR ', ') as following 
FROM followers GROUP BY user_id
```

Results like:

[image]

You can get followers and followings in same query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.user_id, 
o.following,
e.follower
FROM followers f
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT followers.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT follower_id SEPARATOR ', ') as following 
    FROM followers GROUP BY user_id
) as o ON f.user_id = o.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT followers.follower_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id SEPARATOR ', ') as follower 
    FROM followers GROUP BY follower_id
) as e ON f.user_id = e.follower_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, for a given table *tmp*

```
id     |   user_id   |  follower_id
------------------------------------
1            6             7
2            6             8
3            7             6
4            8             15
5            6             9
6            5             7  
7            9             6
8            15            8
```

Here's the query:

```
select t1.user_id, t1.follower_id
from tmp t1
join tmp t2
on t1.user_id = t2.follower_id
and t1.follower_id = t2.user_id
where t1.user_id < t1.follower_id
```

This will give a list of mutual follows, the where clause at the end just ensures that we get one unique record for 'user - follower' mutual follows.

Output:

```
user_id   |  follower_id
------------------------------------
6             7
6             9
8             15
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This Way , its worked for me **followers** and **following**

```
$Followers = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM followers WHERE  follower_id ='$_SESSION[id]'");
echo "Followers :".mysqli_num_rows($Followers);


$Following = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM followers WHERE user_id ='$_SESSION[id]'");
    echo "Followers :".mysqli_num_rows($Followers);
```

**$_SESSION[id]** its your id

..

if you wanna to see other user profiles **NOT YOUR PROFILE**

```
$Following = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM followers WHERE  follower_id ='$_GET[u_id]'");
echo "Following :".mysqli_num_rows($Following);

$Following = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM followers WHERE  user_id ='$_GET[u_id]'");
    echo "Following :".mysqli_num_rows($Following);
```

**$_GET[u_id]** its id of user that your viewing